# How to bind checkbox to variable in JavaFX?

Tags: java, model-view-controller, javafx, checkbox, fxml

I have controller class like this

```
public class Controller{
  private final Model model;

  @FXML
  private CheckBox chbx1;
  @FXML
  private CheckBox chbx2;
  @FXML
  private CheckBox chbx3;

  public Controller(Model model) {
       this.model = model;
   }

  @FXML
  private void initialize(){
     chbx1.selectedProperty().bind(model.initProperty());
  }
}
```

My model class look like this

```
public class Model{
   private final BooleanProperty init = new SimpleBooleanProperty(false);

   public BooleanProperty initProperty() {
      return init;
   }

   public final Boolean getInit() {
      return initProperty().get();
   }

   public final void setInit(Boolean init) {
      initProperty().set(init);
   }
}
```

I want to bind CheckBox to variable in Model. I am currently doing this, but I am getting `CheckBox.selected : A bound value cannot be set.` Error.

The second thing I wanna do is to check, which checkbox was selected or disselected and according to this set boolean variable in model. Is there some way how to do this ?

Comment: The error is self-explanatory - A bound value cannot be set. It means that if you have used binding on one of the property then you should not manually set the value.

Comment: I still dont understand. I am not manually setting the value.

Comment: The built-in event handlers on the checkbox will call `setSelected` when the user checks/unchecks them. Did you intend the binding to be the other way around? What are you trying to do? (At a minimum, this code doesn't make sense because you would have three checkboxes that always had exactly the same state.)

Comment: I have Checkboxex as it is in example. I am also saving values of them to property file and after start of my project I need to get values from property file and set checkboxexaccording to this values in view. Then when user check or uncheck CheckBox I need to save the value to property file. So my idea was to have booleanproperty variable and after start set it to vlaue from properties file and bind checbox to it to update it in view. Is it clear ?

Comment: `checkBox.selectedProperty().bind(someBooleanProperty)` means the checkbox's `selectedProperty` will *always* have the same value as `someBooleanProperty`. This is incompatible with the check box being editable, because the user checking or unchecking the check box would violate the rule established by the binding - this is what causes the exception. It also means that in your code all three checkboxes would always have the same state, which is probably not what you intend. So you probably want `bindBidirectional` and need three properties in your model.

Comment: Thank a lot now i understand my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the user clicks on a `CheckBox`, the control will attempt to modify the `selected`property which will fail for a property that is (uni-directionally) bound.

You could do a bidirectional binding (if you modify the model an the change should result in a change in the ui):

```
chbx1.selectedProperty().bindBidirectional(model.initProperty());
```

if the model can only be modified by the controller, you also use a conventional binding, but the binding needs to be done the other way round:

```
model.initProperty().bind(chbx1.selectedProperty());
```